# How to call async Task GetPosition () from an xamarin.forms app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to fetch Geo code in an `xamarin.forms` app, I am following the below link, can any one tell me how to call `async Task GetPosition()`

I tried `await objOftheclass.GetPosition();` but It failed, can any one help me how to call async method in xamarin

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Geolocator

Comment: You use `await`. What do you mean "it failed"?

Comment: If you have an exception or error message, please post its full output